# romove rows with some specific value in columns

Tags: r, r-package, bioconductor

I like to remove rows contain `chr1_ _random` and then sort my data based on `chr` and `start` columns:

data:

```
Coordinates                                         chr     start       end                                              
chr1_gl000191_random:25220-31247 chr1_gl000191_random     25220     31247                                 
chr1_gl000191_random:28291-31301 chr1_gl000192_random     28291     31301  
chr1:100015775-100016525                         chr1 100015775 100016525       
chr1:10001650-10004925                           chr1  10001650  10004925
```

out put:

```
Coordinates                                         chr     start       end                                               
chr1:10001650-10004925                           chr1  10001650  10004925
chr1:100015775-100016525                         chr1 100015775 100016525
```

Thank you for any suggestion in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For removing rows contain `chr1_ _random` use

```
data <- data[grepl("chr1\\_.*\\_random", data$chr) == FALSE,]
```

Then for sorting use

```
attach(data)
data = data[order(start, end),]
detach(data)
```

Comment: @ Virguez: Thanks ! but sorting method does not work and I get this errore: Error in detach(data) : invalid 'name' argument